# Apache Tomcat/9.0.34 Login on Manager App and Host Manager not working

Tags: login, failed, tomcat9

installed Tomcat on a Ubuntu Machine, worked all properly. Port are open, i can see the Landing Page from Tomcat. When i try to login, the Credentials i put in into the tomcat-users.xml do not work. Need help, i am new to Tomcat :( Login Credentials in the Code are not the correct one :) Just some safety.

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<tomcat-users . . .>

    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <user username="test" password="test" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: You did restart Tomcat after editing the xml?

Comment: with ```sudo systemctl restart tomcat``` aswell with ```./shutdown.sh``` and ```startup.sh```

Comment: </tomcat-users>
</tomcat-users>   I don't think Tomcat will accept that xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the structure of your tomcat-users.xml is wrong.  Try this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <user username="test" password="test" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Problem solved. There was another </tomcat-users> in the Code. I dont get it where it comes from. Used a clean/fresh Install from Tomcat. Maybe i was just blind.

Comment: It took me long enough to see it.